# How to initialize a particular numpy array element value with a set of elements?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a code in which I want to create a multidimensional array of numpy with each element being another array of 3 elements of row vector here is how it looks:

```
a1=np.ndarray([4,4])
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        a1[i,j]=[2,2,2]
```

Now when I try to do so, I get an error:
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Please tell me where I went wrong.
Basically, my aim is to create a numpy ndarray( and not asarray or array) like this:
This is just a rough example of what I want to do.

```
[[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]
[4,4,4],[5,5,5],[6,6,6]
[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,2,4]]
```

Comment: In your `rough example` is the presence or absence of commas and brackets significant?  If I just count [], it looks like you want a (9,3) array.  I also don't understand your distinction between `ndarray`, `asarray` and `array`.  One is a class, the other two functions.

Answer (score 0):

The 3 element vector at every `i, j` location forms a third dimension. Thus the shape of the array should be `[4, 4, 3]` - the third dimension contains 3 elements.

```
a1 = np.ndarray([4, 4, 3])
...
```

Answer (score 0):

your final array will have (4,4,3) shape. so you must reserve this room :

```
a1=np.empty((4,4,3),dtype=int)
# or np.ndarray((4,4,3),int)
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        a1[i,j]=[i,j,i+j] # for exemple
```